# Convert existing XML file from ANSI encoding standard to UTF-8 encoding standard in C#

Tags: c#, xml, encoding, utf-8

I am trying to convert an existing XML file to UTF-8, the encoding is not specified in the file, since it has symbols like the degree (°) and superscript (²) I am assuming it is ANSI encoding. Because of this I am getting an Exception:

> Exception thrown: 'System.Xml.XmlException' in System.Xml.dll
> An exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.dll but was not handled in user code
> Invalid character in the given encoding. Line 5, position 48.

The code I am using to load the file.

```
        XmlDocument xmlDocument;
        xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        string currentDir = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
        //getting the directory
        DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(
        Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(currentDir, @"..\..\" + @"utils\XML\test.xml")));

        //loading the xml file
        xmlDocument.Load(directory.ToString());
```

So my question: Is there a way to programmably convert the encoding using C#?

A way would be to read the file as a String, but this is not feasible because the file is supposed to be very big, making it very hard to work with.

```
        string fileContent = File.ReadAllText(directory.ToString());
        xmlDocument.LoadXml(fileContent);
```

Comment: Your xml is supposed to have the encoding in its declaration. Anyway, you can specify the encoding by using the [`Load(Stream)` overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.load?view=netcore-3.1#System_Xml_XmlDocument_Load_System_IO_Stream_) and passing a [`StreamReader(Stream, Encoding)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_StreamReader__ctor_System_IO_Stream_System_Text_Encoding_)

Comment: Post the beginning of xml so I can see what is really wrong.  The error is on line 5.  The ToString() may cause other errors.  I suspect if you read with XmlReader.Create(filename) this will work.  You may need to add a XmlReaderSetting to ignore some  checks.

Comment: Please check the  following link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/how-to-read-and-write-an-encoded-document

Comment: @jdweng There is no encoding included in the beginning of the file. It looks like this: `<?xml version="1.0" ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't use  XmlDocument or XDocument to make changes to the encoding directly, so I had to find out another way. I read the XML file content using the StreamReader:

```
string currentDir = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(currentDir, @"..\..\" + @"utils\XML\test.xml")));
```

and then load it as a string using XmlDocument

```
XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.LoadXml(sr.ReadToEnd());
```

After that, my solution was to remove the first line from XML and insert a new declaration.

```
XmlDeclaration xmldecl = xmlDocument.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null);
            xmlDocument.InsertBefore(xmldecl, xmlDocument.FirstChild);
            xmlDocument.Save(Path.Combine(currentDir, @"..\..\" + @"utils\XML\test-1.xml"));
```

Finally to remove the invalid characters I just I read the file into a string and replace the unknown character '�' because when it's read as a string all the invalid characters are replaced with this character (the question mark box). What can be done here is replacing the characters with something else (I left it empty for the purpose of my code)

```
var fileContent = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(currentDir, @"..\..\" + @"utils\XML\test-1.xml"));
            fileContent = Regex.Replace(fileContent, "�", "");
            File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(currentDir, @"..\..\" + @"utils\XML\test-1.xml"), fileContent);
```

This is the solution I came up with.